# Fetching a IP from text file using python

Tags: python, regex, file

I am creating custom code for fetching the IP and some other needed details from text file.

Consider the textfile is having following content: tenant_id and IP

```
cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a 45.45.45.45
cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a 1.6.7.3
cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a 1.7.6.2
1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24 2.3.7.5
1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24 6.5.2.1
```

Now I have already created the code for fetching the IP and tenant separately.

**Code is as follows:**

```
files = open("/root/flattext", "r")

# create an empty list
ips = [] 
tenants = []

# read through the files
for text in files.readlines():

    # strip off the \n
    text = text.rstrip()

        # IP and Tenant Fetch
        regex = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})$', text)
        regex1 = re.findall(r'[0-9A-Za-z]{32}', text)

        if regex is not None and regex not in ips:
                ips.append(regex)

        if regex1 is not None and regex1 not in tenants:
                tenants.append(regex1)

ip_valuess = [''.join(ip) for ip in ips if ip]
tenant_ids = [''.join(tenant) for tenant in tenants if tenant]

# cleanup and close files
files.close()
```

So It will be giving result which consists of IP and Tenant_id as separate list.

Here what I need is fetching the IP which is coming under particular tenant ID.

Consider 1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24 as a tenant_id, 
So it should be giving result as 
2.3.7.5 , 6.5.2.1.

Some one please have a look and give me a better way to sort it out.

Comment: Regex is generally for matching / searching. You have a structured file format, why do you feel the need to use a regex? Just parse it, namely using split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`split`** and **`defaultdict`**:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

with open('flattext', 'r') as f:
    for row in f.read().strip().split('\n'):
        if row.strip() != "":
            tenant_id, ip = row.split()
            results[tenant_id].append(ip)

print results.get('1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24', None)
print results.items()
```

**Output:**

```
['2.3.7.5', '6.5.2.1']
```

**And `results` content:**

```
[
  ('1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24', ['2.3.7.5', '6.5.2.1']),
  ('cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a', ['45.45.45.45', '1.6.7.3', '1.7.6.2'])
]
```

Comment: One more query.
Consider this is a results content:

`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24': ['2.3.7.5', '6.5.2.1'], 'cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a': ['45.45.45.45', '1.6.7.3', '1.7.6.2']})`

In this one I need to check whether IP 2.3.7.5 is available for tenant 1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whether is it good to go.?

`ip_list = results.get('1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24', None)
if ip in ip_list:
        print "Yes it is"
else:
        print "Sorry no entry"`

Comment: @iamnewuser, I think you have asked in the wrong answer. The one you selected is the above one

Comment: Ok Thanks , I have one more query

Comment: I am using your code sample. It is working fine.
But some times it is resulting in error like this:
`tenant_id, ip = row.split()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: @iamnewuser I would need to see the whole input it's receiving.

Comment: Hello, Actually issue here was due to the empty line or space being added in file.How can I get rid of it.

Comment: @iamnewuser instead of `for row in f.readlines():` use `for row in f.read().strip().split('\n')`

Comment: But if it have empty line in between again resulting in an error

Comment: @iamnewuser great, but just a question: Why are you using my answer if you set the other one as the answer to your question?

Comment: @iamnewuser thanks! I've update my answer to handle blank lines before, after or between data. Let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why use `regex` just `split` works fine just use `defaultdict`-

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
with open(r"D:\ip.txt",'rb') as fl:
    for i in fl.readlines():
        i=i.strip()
        data[i.split(" ")[0]].append(i.split(" ")[1])
print data.items()
```

Output-

```
[('1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24', ['2.3.7.5', '6.5.2.1']), ('cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a', ['45.45.45.45', '1.6.7.3', '1.7.6.2'])]
```

If your file is not structured and no space to split with then try `regex`-

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
pattern_ip = r'([\d]{1,3}(?=\.|$))'
pattern_tenat = r'^[a-z0-9]{32}'

with open(r"D:\ip.txt",'rb') as fl:
    for i in fl.readlines():
        i=i.strip()
        ip = '.'.join(re.findall(pattern_ip,i))
        tent = ''.join(re.findall(pattern_tenat,i))
        data[tent].append(ip)
print data.items()
```

Output-

```
[('1235b3a73ad24b9c86cf301525310b24', ['2.3.7.5', '6.5.2.1']), ('cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a', ['45.45.45.45', '1.6.7.3', '1.7.6.2'])]
```

See `regex` LIVE <kbd>[DEMOTENANT](https://regex101.com/r/uQ5aD1/1)</kbd> and <kbd>[DEMOIP](https://regex101.com/r/mM2rM0/1)</kbd>